# Javascript assign iframe's form element value to a main window form element value

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe

form1 in the iframe:

```
<iframe id="quoteiframe" ....>
    <form id="form1"...>
       <div id="rate">12.00</div>
    </form>
</iframe>
```

form2 in the main window:

```
<form id="form2" ....>
    <input name="ir" value="" ...>
</form>
```

Is it possible to assign the rate value 12.00 to form2's input element? I've tried:

```
var ifr = document.getElementById('quoteiframe');
var ifrDoc = ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document;                                                        
var theForm = ifrDoc.getElementById('form1');
form2['ir'].value = theForm.getElementById('rate').text();
```

The input element didn't accept the value, still remains blank. By the way, the iframe & main window are not on the same server.

Comment: From MDN 'Scripts trying to access a frame's content are subject to the same-origin policy, and cannot access most of the properties in the other window object if it was loaded from a different domain. This also applies to a script inside a frame trying to access its parent window. Cross-domain communication can still be achieved with window.postMessage.'

Comment: I see, thanks for the information. I had to use a different approach.